# Flask app prints environment variable as object instead of string returned from os.getenv

Tags: python-3.x, flask, environment-variables, pipenv

I have the following code snippet in my main.py:

```
import os
from app import create_app
from models import db, bcrypt
if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
    try:
        PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
    except ValueError:
        PORT = 5555
    env_name = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV', "Please set FLASK_ENV")
    print("env_name: ", env_name)
    app = create_app(env_name)
```

I run it using `flask run` inside `pipenv shell` and bump into the following error in the line which prints out the `env_name`. I have tried both `set FLASK_ENV=development` (Windows 10) and using `.env` but to no avail. I use python-3.8.3

```
(src-4Nvvrxp5) C:\Projects\Python\PythonFlaskRestAPI\src>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "main.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
env_name: <flask.cli.ScriptInfo object at 0x000002D6BA598940>
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 269-678-937
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: How are you setting the env?

Comment: Did you read the question at all before you post any comment?

Comment: My bad, I did read the question once. and Now I have read it again. I am fairly new, so forgive me if I am missing a point. I was under the impression that you set the environ value as such, os.environ["key"] = "value" . Which I do not see anywhere in your code , @kokhowteh

Comment: Nevermind, I reread the question again and just noticed it, my bad  ....  " have tried both set FLASK_ENV=development (Windows 10) and using .env but to no avail"

Comment: Any chance you could provide an [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

So upon further research, I was able to reproduce your problem(somewhat) locally. As you can see in the image below.

[image]

Now the reason this is happening is because of this paragraph from flask official [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#application-discovery):

[image]

What you want to focus on is this :

> If the application factory takes only one argument and no parentheses follow the factory name, the ***ScriptInfo instance is passed*** as a positional argument.

As such there is no error that is occuring, the code is working as expected.

Now if your concern is the fact that (set FLASK_ENV=development) command is not setting it correctly, I would point out that it is indeed setting it correctly as seen here in your OP:

```
(src-4Nvvrxp5) C:\Projects\Python\PythonFlaskRestAPI\src>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "main.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
```

The third line in the terminal out above says "* Environment: development" , whereas the default value according to the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#environments) is "* Environment: production "

Let me know if that resolved your concerns and queries :D . Good Luck!